# Querying a list of tables when you don't know the number of tables

Tags: sql, recursion, common-table-expression

I have a database of tables with table names in the form of tablename_XXXX where X is a unique numeric identifier.

I need to query all of these tables for the claimnumber's that are duplicated across those tables. I do not know how many tables there are as more can be added to the database later and I will still need to search those too.

I tried to use a recursive CTE to build the query to get the list of tables and then iterate through each table and build a temp table with the claimnumbers, then just use a simple group by and count to get the duplicates, but it seems you can't dynamically define the FROM clause in a CTE like that.

```
select * 
from sys.tables 
where NAME like 'tablename_%'
```

This SQL will give me the list of tables I need to search, but how do I then move those table names into a `WHERE` clause?

Is there anyway to build a query to search a list of tables that were found from another query?

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure about this, but I don't think there is a way in pure SQL to do this.

Since I don't think this is possible, I use a jinja template outside of SQL and pass it a list of tables and then have the template render the huge sql statement for me.

The simple way with a list would assume you could hard code the CLAIMNO column because it was the same in every table. If not, you'd have to assemble a dictionary and then loop through that.

```
{%- for t in table_list %}
SELECT '{{ t }}' AS TABLE_NAME, CLAIMNO, COUNT(1) AS NUM_RECORDS FROM {{ t }} GROUP BY 1,2 HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
{{ ' ' if loop.last else ' UNION ALL ' }}
{%- endfor -%}
```

Supplied with a list object like this,

```
table_list:
- DBO.ORDERS
- DBO.SITES
- DBO.VISITS
```

This will render your SQL statement as

```
SELECT 'DBO.ORDERS' AS TABLE_NAME, CLAIMNO, COUNT(1) AS NUM_RECORDS FROM DBO.ORDERS GROUP BY 1,2 HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
 UNION ALL 
SELECT 'DBO.SITES' AS TABLE_NAME, CLAIMNO, COUNT(1) AS NUM_RECORDS FROM DBO.SITES GROUP BY 1,2 HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
 UNION ALL 
SELECT 'DBO.VISITS' AS TABLE_NAME, CLAIMNO, COUNT(1) AS NUM_RECORDS FROM DBO.VISITS GROUP BY 1,2 HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
```

You can try this out at this [website](https://j2live.ttl255.com/) if you'd like, or you can use python which can be useful if you want to query `sys.tables` and dynamically create your list of tables that you then pass to jinja.